# Will internal API calls be treated as DDOS attacks by AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, node.js, socket

I have a nodejs development server. I am currently running on an AWS EC2 micro AMI. I have a hardware device which continuously submits data to this server via socket. The server then calls an API, submits data received from the hardware device after processing and stores it in a local Mongodb instance. The device submits data every 5 seconds. The API currently resides on the same server on a different port, which will be moved to another server later. My server hung after 3 API calls.

1. Is it okay to have API calls every 5 seconds when the socket data is submitted?
2. Should I implement some kind of a queueing mechanism to gather the socket data and process it?
3. Will Amazon consider it as a DDOS attack because the an API is triggered constantly.
4. Am I doing something wrong?

On the later run, my socket server, my API server and my mongodb instance will have it's own dedicated servers. Currently I'm using a development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 and AWS infrastructure in general is designed to handle heavy traffic.  Your 1 request/5 seconds isn't a lot in terms of request frequency, nor would it come close to being considered malicious.

Now your issue of the server hanging after 3 requests is a separate one; it sounds like the application itself needs optimization.  If your data processing is taking too long, then it does sound like you would benefit from Amazon's SQS service; have your listener listen on the port and write to SQS straight away and return.  Have a separate process reading from SQS, processing and writing to Mongo.  SQS is [free for the first 1 million requests per month](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/), and at a rate of 1-request-every-5-seconds, you'll make 535,680 per month.